# Extend the singleton pattern to allow more than one instance

Tags: c++, singleton

How can we extend the singleton method to allow more than one instance in C++. For example, how we can use singleton pattern to ensure that maximum 5 objects of a class is created or allowed

Comment: The singleton pattern doesn't need to be extended, it needs to be buried.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern. Btw if you ever need this you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: How can we extend the prison to allow inmates to be free?

Comment: @buddhabrot: Why you dont link this design pattern? I'm asking this cause I have used it a few times and the Singleton showed that is a good choice when its necessary guarantee that only one instance of a class exists.

Comment: @kist, what is wrong with using plain static classes?

Comment: What's wrong with not limiting the number of instances?

Comment: @Dykam: You got me. But in a multithread enviroment you can have several threads accessing the object, one thread can call a method that change some atributes of the singleton object, while other thread is using it. Well, of couse you can do the same with plain static classes but I think its a little bit uglier.

Comment: @kist, why would it be cleaner as singleton?

Comment: @Dykam, Cause you dont need to put access control in every method. Btw, in singletron the object will be constructed only when it is used(in the first call to the getInstance() method - or something like that)

Comment: A singleton is two things: 1) a globally accessible object and 2) no other instances of the same type exist. I'm tempted to say you never need to enforce #2. Sometimes you may want #1, but the language already has that built-in: global variables. Regarding thread-safety you can make any old object threadsafe, no need for singletonness. In fact, if you allow more than one copy it may be possible to solve the threading issues by simply giving each thread a different instance. More singleton myths deconstructed here: http://jalf.dk/singleton

Comment: @kist: how come you don't need access control in every method? Where you do put it? (I assume that by access control you mean some kind of mutex acquisition). The fact that there is only one doesn't make anything safe for use by multiple threads. In fact, it's usually the opposite.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes. Yes, some kind of mutex,  and this kind of stuff can be put on getInstance() method.

Comment: @kist: that will only protect the *creation* and *retrieval* of the singleton, no? What about two threads that call `singleton::getInstance().increment();` and `singleton::getInstance().decrement();`? Will that be free of races?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes. Got your point. I did not intend to refer to race conditions in my commend above, sorry about that. I was referring to the problem when one thread call a method of our singletron(and some data of the singletron is changed), other thread takes control and call another method(and some data of the singletron is changed too), when the first thread return, the data altered by the second one can interfere in the result of the method called by it.

Comment: @kist, with .Net at least, a (static) class in only initialized when it is first accessed. You can even give it a static constructor.

Comment: @Dykam. Ow, nice. I dont know anything about .Net. But, if .Net has this then, really, I dont see any purpose of using Singleton pattern. I talked based only in my programming experience(only c++ :( ).

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern doesn't guarantee that a *maximum* of one object may be created, it creates one object as the program is initialized and destroys it as the program is terminated.

Use a factory function to control creation of an object representing a limited resource.

```
class limited {
private:
    static int instance_count;

    limited() { // users cannot directly call the constructor
        ++ instance_count;
    }

    limited( const limited & ); // do not implement so users cannot copy

public:
    ~limited() {
        -- instance_count;
    }

    static limited make() { // this factory function must be used instead
        if ( limited::instance_count >= 5 ) {
            throw std::runtime_error( "some kind of overflow" );
        }
        return limited();
    }
};
```

Comment: Of course you do realise that `limited` could be copied, which would completely annihilate your control over the number of instances... right :) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Okaaay… fixed that, C++03 style. I have my doubts, one way or another. Edit — bah, now it doesn't compile without copy elision. Really, I don't care.

Comment: why is limited_make() declared friend?

Comment: @pezcode: Eh, I tend to prefer `friend` over `static` but the latter is more idiomatic here. Updated.

Comment: @pezcode: the name is `make`, which returns a `limited`. It is declared as friend so that you can type `limited l = make()` rather than as a static function which would be a bit heavier `limited l = limited::make()`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why make a `make` function and not throw from the constructor directly ? But I agree, it's a stupid problem anyway.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's all just a shot in the dark… I think it's cleaner to `throw` before attempting to construct anything, for example nonstatic members. But yeah, other patterns work.